# MoveToElement and click in protractor nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have to click on a checkbox in our application.Am able to successfully click in selenium java with the below code but am not able to do it in protractor nodejs. Can someone please help.

Selenium- Java :

```
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

I have tried multiple things in protractor nodejs like clicking using javascript, mouseMove and perform .But its not working. Please suggest as per the above code.

Comment: When you say it is not working, what is the error ?

Comment: its throwing this error :  Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 180000 milliseconds

Comment: Where does actions come from in Java? Which library / library path?

Comment: @cnishina : Its coming from org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions

Comment: Maybe use the Actions class from selenium-webdriver? https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/input_exports_Actions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set up protractor with nodeJS following the setup guide on their website: https://www.protractortest.org/#/

Then it's as simple as:

```js
const element = browser.$("input[type=checkbox].myCheckboxClass#myCheckboxID");
await element.click();
```